# When is filter_input() used versus filter_var()?

Tags: php, sanitization

I traditionally use a `filter_var()` function for sanitizing `$_GET` and `$_POST` data, such as:

```
 $foo =  filter_var($_GET['foo'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

but PHP also has a function `filter_input()`, which has a different syntax to accomplish the same thing:

```
$foo = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'foo', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

Are these just synonyms?  Is there an advantage to using one over the other?

I have checked the man pages, but I don't see a lot of difference (only whether/how an error is reported).  Semantically/best practice, what makes the most sense?

Comment: `filter_var` takes any variable, so you have to look out for undefined variable errors yourself. `filter_input` instead uses the original values of `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE`, `$_ENV` or `$_SERVER`, that means any modification made to these variables will not be taken into account. See https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php#115086

Comment: @CharlotteDunois, so filter_input is a more specific case of filter_var?  It seems strange that PHP would have another function with different syntax and so little added benefit.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One of the main differences is how they handle undefined variables/indexes.  If `$_GET['foo']` doesn't exist:

```
$foo = filter_var($_GET['foo'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

Returns an empty string `""` and generates:

> Notice: Undefined index: foo

So you would normally need to wrap this in a `if(isset($_GET['foo']))`.

Whereas:

```
$foo = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'foo', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

Returns `NULL` and does not generate an error.

**Note**: The `filter_input` function does not operate on the current `$_GET` and `$_POST` superglobals, rather it is prepopulated and independent of those arrays.

If `$_GET['foo']` does not exist but is created in the script, it will not be seen by `filter_input`:

```
$_GET['foo'] = 1;
$foo = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'foo', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

Will return `null`.

Comment: So the only benefit then is saving the extra `isset()` check?  As I mentioned in my other comment above, why would the makers of PHP bother with an extra function with a different syntax for so little extra benefit?  Not really a rhetorical question, but I don't know if there is an easy answer...

Comment: @Sablefoste Cleanliness is exactly what we want.

Comment: Okay, I will accept the answer, and immediately forget `filter_input`.  Because only having to know one type of syntax is cleaner (to me) then shorter but special case code.  Thank you for the answer!  ;)

Comment: Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php#99124 for more differences.

Comment: Can `filter_input` be used to sanitise as well as validate? I'm not having any luck getting it to work with the sanitise filters.

Comment: @HashimAziz You would need to ask a question with code and show what you want.